# CentOS yum remove postgres is not working

Tags: centos, postgresql, yum

I am trying to remove postgres from my CentOS server completely so I could start from the beginning, I did some seriously demented stuff!!!! one of them is deleting "/etc/init.d/postgres"

But then I cant remove it!! Things smile at me? Impossible!

I did the following command `yum remove postgresql*`

```
Removed
   postgresql84-server.x86_64 0:8.4.7-1.el5_6.1
Complete!
```

Then I wanted to check if it was removed

```
yum list installed | grep post
postgresql84-server.x86_64               8.4.7-1.el5_6.1               installed
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried removing 'postgresql84-server'? That looks like the package name

Comment: Yup I tried that with no luck, the package still "installed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the reinstallation by `rpm -e --justdb --nodeps postgresql84-server` and then running a `yum install postgresql84-server`.